# GridView's column is not a straight line when scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I was developing a Android GridView containing many images. **When scroll up after scroll to the bottom of the list, the list's column is no longer a straight line.**

Screenshot :

[image]
[image]

The more strange is reaction does not occur in another list (in paralympic tab of screenshot) even using same adapter and GridView. But other page has a less item. So I think whether the difference in the item count. (Just my guess) There are 40 items in the problem list.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/sports_gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sports_iv_item_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sports_tv_item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Why Is This phenomenon is happening? How can I fix it?

Thanks all :)

Comment: I think this has something to do with the amount of text under a picture. If you shrink all of it to one line, will this still happend?

Comment: @Thealon Oh.. The bug was fixed after reduce all the text to one line! But I have to use all those text.. Hmm.. I do not know how to solve..

Comment: @Stella maby change the font size if the string is longer than one line?

Comment: @Thealon Thanks thealon, It's good solution.I reduce the font size as small as possible, nevertheless, some texts has two line.. And this size is not seem so small. T-T  (http://cowkite.dothome.co.kr/gridview.png)

Comment: How about make everything 2 lines (so insert a blank line)? this way it will always fit with a nice font size.

Comment: @Thealon Wow! You're very smart and have a good sense lol  But how can I extend all the text in two lines? For example, for short words such 'Archery'

Comment: Thanks @Stella, to be honest I don't know alot about this subject. Where do you get the text from? a database or a text file? Also are you using java? if so you can loop trough all the text and if the amount of characters is smaller than two lines you could insert a newline.

Comment: @Thealon It has not yet been defined. (Because I made just prototype.) For now, just enter the text. (Example : mGridArray.add(image_resource, "Blah Blah");)

Comment: @Stella Yeah you can just make it:  "Bla bla\n" I think this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView doesn't really support items with varying height, so you can do the following:

- Let all of your items be the same height: in this case it's quite 
  simple, add android:lines="2" to sports_tv_item_title, to make all of
  your titles 2 lines tall.
- Use a custom android staggered gridview, like    https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid (first hit of google)
- I belive a RecyclerView with a StaggeredLayoutManager can do the
  same for you.

Comment: I use first way, and it successfully operates. Really Thanks :)